# Import CSV file to oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle

Is there a simple Java library or approach that will take a SQL query and load data in a CSV file to oracle database. Pls help

Comment: `will take a SQL query and load data in a CSV file to oracle database.` from where you want to read and where to write ?

Comment: I want to load data from CSV file to a oracle DB table using a java programme. That's all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For similar tasks I usually use **Groovy scripts** as it's really easy and quick to write and runs on the JVM off course.

...an example:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def file1 = new File(/C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\Book1.csv/)
def reader = new FileReader(file1)

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXX:XXXX:XXX", "SCHEMA",
      "USER", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

reader.each { line ->
   fields =  line.split(';')
   sql.executeInsert("insert into YOUR_TABLE values(${fields[0]},${fields[1]},${fields[2]})")
}
```

*It's a basic example, if you have double quotes and semi columns in your csv you will probably want to use something like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to handle that.*

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use Java to load a data file into a table unless it is absolutely necessary. Instead, I'd recommend Oracle's command-line [SQL*Loader](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_concepts.htm#SUTIL003) utility which was designed specially for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform each line in the CSV with regular expressions, to make an insert query, and then send to Oracle (with JDBC).

Answer (score 0):

I think this tool will help you for any type of database import-export problem.

http://www.dmc-fr.com/home_en.php

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that CSV in a file on the database server or can you store it there? Then you may try to have Oracle open it by declaring a DIRECTORY object for the path the file is in and then create an EXTERNAL TABLE which you can query in SQL afterwards. Oracle does the parsing of the file for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to Python you can do bulk load using SQL*Loader

```
loadConf=('sqlldr userid=%s DATA=%s control=%s LOG=%s.log BAD=%s.bad DISCARD=%s.dsc' % (userid,datafile, ctlfile,fn,fn,fn)).split(' ')

p = Popen(loadConf, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False, env=os.environ)

output, err = p.communicate()
```

It's will be much faster that row insert.

I uploaded basic working example [here](https://github.com/alexbuz/CSV_Loader_For_Oracle/blob/master/loader.py).